# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined myTimer

Tags: javascript, frontend, dom-events

I have a web site which has a form where the user can enter their email, and upon submitting is sent to the next page. When I enter the email on this page, and I analyze the console, I see the following exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined myTimer @ VM567 content.js:43(anonymous function) @ VM567 content.js:40

When I click on this, I see `content.js` as:

```
var gtmSnippet = document.createElement('script');
gtmSnippet.title = 'TMI-INJECTED-GTM-CONTAINER-SNIPPET';
gtmSnippet.id = 'tmigtmsnippet';

var gtmTrigger = document.createElement('div');
gtmTrigger.id = 'tmitriggerholder';

var THEID;   

function DB_setValue(name, value, callback) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[name] = value;
    console.log("Data Saved!");
    chrome.storage.local.set(obj, function() {
        if(callback) callback();
    });
}
    
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "SnippetPlease"}, function(response) {
    THEID = response.farewell;
    if(response.farewell.length > 0){
        gtmSnippet.text = "//GTM CONTAINER INJECTION: \n(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','" + response.farewell + "'); \n//GTM CONTAINER INJECTION ENDS\n";
        
        // Get a value saved in a form.
        var theValue = THEID;
        // Check that there's some code there.
        if (!theValue) {
            return;
        }
        else{
            DB_setValue('theid',theValue,function(){});
        }
    }
});  

40 var interval = setInterval(function(){myTimer()}, 0.1);

41 function myTimer() {
42    if((document.body != null) && (THEID.length>0)){
43      // INJECT CONTAINER SNIPPET
44      document.body.appendChild(gtmSnippet);
45      
46      stopInterval();
47  }
}

function stopInterval() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

I have just started tinkering with JavaScript and I don't understand why this error is occurring, and

How I could resolve it?

Comment: You need to post the code of the calling scope and tell us what lines are those with numbers 43 and 40. We cannot _guess_ that.

Comment: @arkascha please check the edits

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I have shown the entire file content.js. Please take a look

Comment: You are trying to access the property `length` of some var `THEID`. Apparently that var does _not_ contain what you expect. Certainly not something with a property `length`. That is where you have to start investigating. I suggest you dump the variable right before that line 42 where you access the property and fail: `console.log(THEID);`

Comment: Change `(THEID.length>0)` to `(typeof THEID !== "undefined")` - [Why is Global State so Evil?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

Comment: THEID will always be undefined outside the function scope.

Comment: @Andreas content.js is a file in chrome-extensions. How can I edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The functions are synchronous**

The variable `THEID` is assigned with value in an asynchronous function:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "SnippetPlease"}, function(response) {
    THEID = response.farewell;
    ..
```

**Which means it will remain `undefined` until the response message is received by the callback function above.**

Where your time interval (*which is too small gap of time*) below tries to access the value of `THEID`, it cannot guarantee that the response has already been received and the value of `THEID` has already been set. So you encounter `undefined`.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){myTimer()}, 0.1);

function myTimer() {
   // This function will be executed before the response is received
   // by chrome.runtime.sendMessage()
   if((document.body != null) && (THEID.length>0)){
     ...
     ...
```

**One way to fix this?**

You may consider execute your logic in the response callback instead of using the time interval to check. So your code may become:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "SnippetPlease"}, function(response) {
    THEID = response.farewell;
    ..
    ..
    // At this point of time, THEID is set from the response.
    if((document.body != null) && (THEID.length>0)){
        // INJECT CONTAINER SNIPPET
        document.body.appendChild(gtmSnippet);
    }
});
```

**Or another way**

Short circuit if `THEID` is undefined as follows:

```
function myTimer() {
   // This function will be executed before the response is received
   // by chrome.runtime.sendMessage()
   if((document.body != null) && THEID && THEID.length>0)){
       ...
       ...
```

So you can still use your time interval approach with little modification.